# P67 Sabertooth shows no volumes when installing OS in RAID mode

Tags: windows, installation, raid

I'm having difficulties installing Windows 7 onto my RAID volume using a ASUS Sabertooth P67 motherboard. I have 2x Samsung 840 SSDs plugged into the 2x black Intel 6gbit sockets.

I've done the following:

- Updated the motherboard BIOS to the latest version (3602)
- Ensured that the SATA option in the UEFI BIOS is set to RAID mode (screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAJWs.png)
- Created a RAID0 volume in the Intel RAID setup (CTRL+I) and ensured it is set to bootable
- Downloaded the appropriate Intel SATA RAID Drivers and put them on my memory stick with the Windows 7 SP1 install image.

I enter the Windows 7 setup, and it asks me to provide the driver - I provide the driver and it still says that it can't find any drives to install on. If I switch the BIOS to use AHCI mode then I can continue but then I lose my RAID setup.

What am I missing?

Edit: [RAID configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/713GF.jpg) and [Installation error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATOXm.jpg)

Edit: Turned out to be a bad installation image. Grabbed a fresh one and it worked fine. Weird.

Comment: I surprised nobody else has provided any help. I am going through a very similar situation and I am watching this posting for ideas.

Comment: Maybe helpful post here: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-system/system-image-file-wont-restore-on-newly-created/9a968d83-ca5a-4a71-85e2-a013d209c713

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the RAID drivers off the ASUS website?
If so, it might be worth trying the ones direct from Intel.

Comment: I've tried both the drivers supplied by ASUS and the latest RST drivers supplied by Intel (specifically  http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&ProdId=2101&DwnldID=22194&ProductFamily=Software+Products&ProductLine=Chipset+Software&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+Rapid+Storage+Technology+(Intel%C2%AE+RST)&lang=eng ) . They show as the same device name for the controller, but neither seem to show the RAID volume.